# Allow authenticated users to fill out fields in nodes that only they can see

Tags: nodes, users

Is it possible in Drupal 7 to allow users to fill out their OWN values for particular fields in a content type?

For example, we want our authenticated users to be able to save nodes to a dashboard. For each node they save there are 5-7 fields we want to make available for the user to enter data into...but ONLY that user should be able to see the notes.

On their dashboard, using Views, they will then see a list of their saved nodes in tabular format with columns that include the data they filled out for each of those fields, as well as the other information that comes from the nodes that the authenticated user can't edit (ie. the title, etc.).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use field permission to set limit to each field
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

In field permission,
You can set fields that can edit by an authenticated user and can only edit by an admin role, etc.

Comment: Thanks - will this allow each individual user to have their own, personal values for each field in question? It seems this module is more just to allow people of a certain permission to make overall changes to a field. I want each user to have THEIR OWN values for each field in question.

Comment: From module page: 'Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is'. Listed permissions include view permission.

Comment: Sure, this module set permissions in content type page. So a user is available to enter their own values to the questions you provided. I'm not sure is this what your question mean?

Comment: I'll test it out but let me clarify: say each node has a field called 'location'. I then want each user to be able to fill out that field for the same node with their own value so that the value is different for each user who entered a value in the field for that node. Example: user Bob enters 'California' for the location field for node (title: EXAMPLE 1) but user Jeremy enters 'Colorado' for the location field for the same node. Each user is unaware that the other user is entering data into this field and when they view the record only see the value that THEY entered for that field.

Comment: Oops, no. It needs to work on different nodes. I think it's hard to achieve this in "one" node.

Comment: `I think it's hard to achieve this in "one" node` He could use views to make it seem as if it was 1 node, when it's a node per user.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by how I would use views to make it seem like it was 1 node?